# TreeView - Jtree (NetBeans) How to add a description to a node

Tags: java, netbeans, treeview, jtree

Im making a simple treeview on NetBeans and id like to know how can i add a description to a determined selected node, through a button that have a function that will associate to a lable.

[Click to see Treeview Image here](http://s4.postimg.org/crq21dg0d/treeview2.jpg)

the link shows the image of what i want to do, by clicking ">>" it will add a description to that lable and associate to that selected node.

this is the code for the ">>" button.

```
private void add2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
   lTree2.setText(tf2.getText());
}
```

obviously this isnt what i want, i just put here show what i want.

Answer (score 0):

You want to create your own class for tree nodes, as a subclass of whatever you're using now, adding a `description` field and corresponding accessors in the subclass. For example, if you're using `DefaultMutableTreeNode`:

```
class MyNode extends DefaultMutableTreeNode {
    private String description;
    ...
    public void setDescription(String descr) {
        description = descr;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
}
```

Once you've done that, in your `actionPerformed()` for the button you want to get the selected tree node, get the description out of it, and set the text in the label:

```
private void add2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
{                                     
    MyNode node = (MyNode)tree.getLastSelectedPathComponent();
    String descr = node.getDescription();
    lTree2.setztext(descr);
 }
```

Comment: thats not what im looking for, but ty for answer

Comment: you may want to clarify your question then :-)

Comment: all i want is: select a already created node, type in the text field, click the ">>" button and what i typed is shown on the description lable, associated to that node.

Comment: Ah. ok, then you should register a listener with the text area, so you can catch every key entered. In the listener, call a method that modifies the string of the currently selected node, and repaint the tree.